# Managed to lock myself out of an SSRS folder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am System Administrator, System User, and all roles on the home directory for an SSRS 2008R2 instance. Stupidly whilst amending some access to a folder which had it's own set of permissions I thought 'Steph, you shouldn't be granted access like that, remove it and add your team's group'.  This was very stupid as now I can't get in and the team can't get in either.

Any idea how to remove this folder or add myself back in?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sudo will let you edit the permissions again even if you don't currently have rights to view the directory & contents.

If you've simply assigned it to the wrong group, 
`sudo chgrp -R right-group /that/directory`

Or if you've assigned the right group but haven't given the group permission to read or write,
`sudo chmod -R ug+rw /that/directory`

And you know -R means recursive so take that out if you don't want to change everything in that directory.

If you don't have the permission to *see* the permissions, 
`sudo ls -al /that/directory`